# Apply a Regex with a conditional lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose those sentences:

> My name is James Bond
>
> My name is the famous James Bond

I want to capture `James Bond`.

If I apply `((?<=is)(.*)`, it takes `James Bond` for the first and `the famous James Bond` for the second.

If I apply `((?<=famous)(.*)`, it takes James Bond for the second sentence.

Doing that does not work, logically:

```
((?<=famous)|(?<=is))(.*)
```

Is it possible to end up with one regex returning `James Bond` in both cases?
As the Regex engine parser works, I'm pretty sure that a programmatic way is more relevant for this use case, but I'm not so sure.

**EDIT-----------**
The Regex should handle any case where there is a "is" or/and "famous", not only those both sentences, taken as examples.

Comment: What are your selection criteria ?

Comment: If these are your only two cases, then this is relatively simple. If you really want to be able to recognise people names out of an arbitrary string, then your regex is going to become _very_ complicated.

Comment: Sorry, ```((?=SA)|(?=Société))``` is not relevant at all for this use case, bad typo ;) Updated.

Comment: Do you mean like `^.*(?:is|famous) (.*)$` https://regex101.com/r/WK52vV/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the last occurrence of `is` or `famous`:

```
.*(?:famous|is)\s*(.*)
```

The result is in Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9NvYSJ/1).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:famous|is)` - a `famous` or `is` substring (use word boundaries if they must be whole word)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: After testing your solution, the trick seems to be to start with ```.*```. Great

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to phrase your regex pattern:

```
My name is.*?([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*)
```

This assumes that following the phrase `My name is` there would be one or more capitalized words, which would correspond to the actual name being referred to earlier.

### Demo

This matches both occurrences of `James Bond`, and should be suitable for you to use, assuming that your regex tool/language supports capture groups.

Comment: I updated my OP to be more accurate.
The Regex should be able to handle any similar sentences.

Comment: Your new requirement does not make good sense to me.  How do you know that the presence of the word `is` means that what follows is a name?  `I think that eating pancakes is good` ... but there is no name here.

Comment: We would assume that it's a name following.

Comment: By the way, +1 since you effectively targeted my first version of the OP ;)